# C++ input in string or char[]?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, char

I've had recently a question to ask that's been bothering me for days. Has the string type some type of memory management already or what, because I'm able to do such a thing

```
string a;
cin >> a;
```

Without knowing how long is a going to be. Why would some people(some from youtube tutorials) use char array(C style) and then take care of the indexing when they could just do it simpler with string types?

Thanks!

Comment: Because they're old-fashioned and haven't adopted the STL way of doing things.

Comment: Maybe because a lot of people were taught C++ as C with classes instead as what C++ and the standard library really is.

Comment: Or they learned C++ a long time ago. Or they think there's too much performance overhead from the standard classes.

Comment: Most C++ tutorials are bad

Comment: @NathanOliver - What we got in college was a hodge-podge of C/C++.  We used cin/cout and strings, but vectors/maps/lists/pairs were never mentioned.  When we needed those, we had to roll our own with new/delete.  I'm guessing whoever made those tutorials had a similar experience of mixing C-isms and C++-isms.

Comment: @Mr.Llama I have seen that a lot.  I think it is a real shame the way C++ is taught in many places.  And you can forget C++11 showing up in most of those places anytime soon.

Comment: `std::string` has a big overhead compared to simple char arrays.

Comment: Okay, that's explains everything, as I thought :) thanks guys, I just don't get these haters downvoting, imho this is a very important thing to know(if you're actually about to understand the language in detail)